# Meteor Template instances lifecycle

Tags: meteor

I'm saving a string in a template instance's data object;
the string is initialized on template.rendered, and can be updated by a control on the template; then it is submitted to a method that saves its value in a collection:

```
Template.myTemplate.rendered = function() {
    this.data.myValue = "aaa";
}

Template.myTemplate.events({
     "click #updateMyValue": function(event, template) {
         if (template.data.myValue = "aaa") template.data.myValue = "bbb";
         else template.data.myValue = "ccc";
     },
     "click #submit": function(event, template) {
         Meteor.call('update', template.data);
     }
});
```

The first time I click #submit, everything is ok; but then template.data.myValue becomes undefined; the click on #submit does not cause the refresh of the page, so I expected the template instance to persist with all its data;
can someone explain why "myValue" is lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not set properties on `template.data`, it's a Meteor reserved property containing the template current data context (read-only).

You appear to be confused between `=` (variable assignment) and `==` (comparison operator).

Inside single page apps, you should always prevent the default behavior of the form submit event to happen.

Try this code instead :

```
Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function() {
  this.myValue = "aaa";
});

Template.myTemplate.events({
  "click #updateMyValue": function(event, template) {
    if (template.myValue == "aaa"){
      template.myValue = "bbb";
    }
    else{
      template.myValue = "ccc";
    }
  },
  "click #submit": function(event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();
    Meteor.call("update", template.myValue);
  }
});
```